# How to use string as a key to update object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that accepts the path in an object and makes that the key.

for example, if I wanted to update the city, which is is a child object of a company, which is a child object of a property I could do something like this:
      **originalObj['property']['company']['city'] = test**

Here is my code so far:

```
function updateObj(path, value){
  let valuePath = path.split(',')
  let key=''
  for(let i=0; i<valuePath.length ; i++){
    key = key+`[valuePath[${i}]]`
  }
   //key = [valuePath[0]] [valuePath[1]] [valuePath[2]]
  originalObj[key] = value
  }

setObj('property,company,city', test)
```

Comment: Oh, interesting. This isn't hard, but it makes for a nice homework exercise in a JavaScript 101 course.

Comment: What have you tried… what is the question?

Answer (score 3):

You could save the last key of the path and use a temporary object for getting the final object for assigning the value.

```js
function updateObj(path, value) {
    var valuePath = path.split(','),
        last = valuePath.pop(),
        temp = object;

    for (let i = 0; i < valuePath.length; i++) {
        temp = temp[valuePath[i]];
    }
    temp[last] = value;
}

var object = { property: { company: { city: 'London' } } };

updateObj('property,company,city', 'New York');

console.log(object);
```

With [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function updateObj(path, value) {
    var valuePath = path.split(','),
        last = valuePath.pop();

    valuePath.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = value;
}

var object = {};

updateObj('property,company,city', 'New York');

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateObj(obj, path, value){
 path.split(",").slice(0,-1).reduce((obj, key) => obj[key] || (obj[key] = {}), obj)[path.split(",").pop()] = value;
}
```

Comment: This is an amazing one-liner that should never be used in anywhere of one's code.

Comment: redundant split

Comment: @intervalia still shorter than a declaration or an IIFE to cache it

Comment: @derek the same applies to the question in general, doesnt it?

Comment: @JonasW. I can see some legitimate uses out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function setObj(originalObj, path, value){
  var parts = path.split(',');
  var lastKey = parts.pop();
  var obj = originalObj;

  parts.forEach(
    function(key) {
      key = key.trim();
      obj[key] = obj[key] || {};
      obj = obj[key];
    }
  );

  obj[lastKey] = value;
}

  var originalObj = {};
  var test = "This is a test";
  setObj(originalObj, 'property,company,city', test)

  console.log(JSON.stringify(originalObj,0,2));
```

It walks through your list and creates sub objects for all but the last. It then uses the last as the key to store the `value`.

The advantage to this code is that you don't assume the original Object variable name. And, if you wanted it to be pure and not to affect the original object structure then you could make these minor changes:

```
function setObj(originalObj, path, value){
  var parts = path.split(',');
  var lastKey = parts.pop();
  var newObj = Object.assign({}, originalObj);
  var obj = newObj;

  parts.forEach(
    function(key) {
      obj[key] = Object.assign({}, obj[key] || {});
      obj = obj[key];
    }
  );

  obj[lastKey] = value;
  return newObj;
}

  var originalObj = {animals: {dog:"bark",cat:"meow"},property:{company:{name:"Fred's Things"}}};
  var test = "This is a test";
  var result = setObj(originalObj, 'property,company,city', test)


  console.log(JSON.stringify(originalObj,0,2));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result,0,2));
```