# JS reduceRight is causing arrays to become objects, how can I fix the logic?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, reduce

I have an json object:

```
json = {
    "array": [80, 50]
}
```

A third party `jsoneditor`, returns a path variable as a list of strings or index to the value. I use event listeners to detect changes to the value and I store those changes in a separate object to later submit to a form.

For example, if I change `50` to `60`, this is what is returned:

```
node.path = ["array", 1]
node.value = 60
```

I am using `reduceRight()` to normally map the changes to the object to the `changed` object, however when the value is an Array it is converting the array to an object.

```
let delta = node.path.reduceRight((obj, elem) => ({[elem]: obj}), node.value)

//returns
delta = {array: {1: 60}}

//instead of 
delta = {array: [80, 60]}
```

How can I check the original `json` and if the field is an Array object, don't reduce this into an object but keep the original Array and update the Array with the changed value within the Array? I need to submit the entire array into the form.

**EDIT:**
I know that I can do some custom logic within the reduce to check the original json and get the `unchanged` part of the array. I just dont know how to achieve that

```
let delta = node.path.reduceRight( function (obj, elem) { 
    //some logic here to account for arrays and get original array list and change only slected index
    else { 
        return {[elem]: obj}), node.value 
    } 
});
```

**EDIT:**
Alternatively, how can can I get the nested keys from the `node.path` and find the original array and then just update the array index? The path can sometimes be nested sothe path is always going to be the Array-like structure.

```
//this does not work
let orig_key_val = json[node.path]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with `reduceRight`. Your reducer function returns an object. You'd have the same result with a plain `reduce`.

Comment: How do you expect to get the value at the 0th index: `80`?

Comment: Yes, and your custom logic right now is "return a single object".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47490773/how-to-use-string-as-a-key-to-update-object same basic concept, except instead of a string, you have an array.

Comment: yes but i still have the original so i intend to retrieve the 0th place via that original "unchanged" part

Comment: Not sure if you want to UPDATE the `json` with the `60` value at the given `path`. OR you get the `60` AFTER the update to `json` and you are trying to construct the delta object.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using reduce at all really, since you're passing the `node.value` as an initial value, but then just ignoring it and explicitly assigning by referencing the variable outside the loop. Just use a `for..of` or `while`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, finally... I used a regular `reduce()` and check if the key is an Array if it is store my original Array into a `tmp` object and save that key. The next time the `reduce()` comes around, if the `index` is on the last path element then set the `tmp[tmp_key][key]` to my target value and return the *adjusted for Array* object instead.

I can see how this will not work for nested json objects but for now I dont have any... Unless someone can show me how to figure that one out this is my implementation for now.

```
let tmp = {};
let tmp_key;
let delta = node.path.reduce((val, key, index, array) => {
    if (Array.isArray(json[key])) {
        tmp[key] = json[key]
        tmp_key = key;
    } else if (Object.keys(tmp).length !== 0 && index === node.path.length-1) {
        tmp[tmp_key][key] = node.value;
        return tmp
    } else
        return {[key]: val}

}, node.value);
```